# Best way to run recombining parallel python code on cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, optimization, cloud

I have a python optimization program that goes something like this:

```
def optimize_score(alpha=0.5, init_point=tuple(np.ones(48)/48),total_paths=5000, iteration_size=0.02,iteration_limit=20):
    best_point=init_point
    point_size=np.size(init_point)
    scores=np.zeros(point_size)
    for i in range(iteration_limit):
        #improve init_point 20 times
        for j in range(point_size):
            #find best directional improvement of previous best point
            current_point=best_point*(1-iteration_size)
            current_point[j]=current_point[j]+iteration_size
            scores[j]=get_score(alpha=alpha, point=current_point,total_paths=total_paths)
        
        best_direction=scores.index(min(scores))
        best_point=best_point*(1-iteration_size)
        best_point[best_direction]=best_point[best_direction]+iteration_size


    
    return best_point

def get_score( alpha=0.5,point=tuple(np.ones(48)/48),total_paths=5000):

    result=np.ones(total_paths)
    for k in range(total_paths):
        result[k]=get_result(path=k, point=point)
    reward=result[0]
    risk=reward-min(result)
    score=risk-alpha*(risk+reward)
    return score
```

`get_result` is quite long so I won't post it here. But essentially it returns a single floating number and is reading from a small database of less than 100,000 lines of data

I'm trying to split the simulation calculations using the cloud because the simulation takes too long on a single computer. I found an example using google cloud, but the tutorial specifically said it cannot handle recombining parallel calculation. Anyone has an example on how to do this and what's the best service for this kind of task?

Comment: Could you explain what is `recombining parallel calculation`?

Comment: @ ferdy What I mean is, multiple steps of parallel calculations where the next  step is going to be dependent on result from the previous step. I imagine there is going to be a master code assign work to all the computers, collect output automatically and continue assign the next batch of work.

Comment: Writing code to do parallel job is easier if we know the process flow. For example you run 5000 simulations, what is the output of these simulations? What is result1? How result1 is calculated. I would suggest you write a minimal reproducible code.

Comment: @ ferdy edited the original post to include code. it seems like i can parallels process `j` in `optimize_score` or `k` in `get_score` or both. But i cannot parallels `i` since it would need result from previous iteration. Both `i` and `j` returns a single floating number, but `get_result` requires reading from a small database to run (not sure how that plays out on the cloud)

Comment: You have an io in get_result() then. You can try a thread worker in k. Your performance may now depend on get_Result(). Or you can try a process worker in j. Performance may also depends on what hardware is in the cloud. Try both and compare.

Comment: @ferdy can you spell it out for me? What is IO and thread worker? How do I apply them to my program? What web service shoud I use? Ect.

Comment: IO is input/output. Reading from db is an io operation. You can launch multiple threads concurrently to get result[0], result[1], ... for k=1 ... n, to get the data from db faster. Search for python multithreading and multiprocessing. There are a lot of examples in the web. Come back if you have not figured it out, I will create an example. Sorry I cannot recommend what web service to use.

Comment: @ferdy, The database is very small and I was making do with numpy.where to get what i need. most of the cpu time are spent on financial calculations such as numpy_financial.pv. I did find lots of python multithreading examples, but they are mostly for a single computer. I'm wondering if there's a script or module that allows me to do multithreading on multiple computers automatically. Since i is sequential, I can't really setup the same code on multiple computers

Comment: I would suggest to use first with a single computer. Use multithreading to read data from database. There are libraries on using multiple computers you can search for it.